# Is there a health difference between equally lean red meat vs poultry?

Tags: nutrition, diet, meat

I am aware that in general, poultry is preferable to red meat for a healthy diet. What I am not clear about is whether the reason for this is *because* red meat is much fattier and caloric than poultry or if there are additional reasons.

To make this question concrete, let's suppose I want to eat a burger every day for lunch. Would it be healthier for me to choose 85% lean ground turkey over 85% lean ground beef, or are those options identical on health grounds due to their identical fat content?